# soap web service in android

Tags: android, web-services, soap

```
Activity extends Activity {
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                  t1 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString().trim();
                     t2 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2)).getText().toString().trim();

                     webAccess();



                }
            });
           }


        public void webAccess(){
            thread = new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    try{
                        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                         request.addProperty("LoginID",t1);
                        request.addProperty("Password",t2);
                        request.addProperty("Token","21220150145");
                        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                        envelope.dotNet = true;
                        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                        System.out.println(request);
                        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();


                        System.out.println(response);


                        String xml = response.toString();

                        Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
                                .parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));




                        NodeList statNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Return"); //parent tag
                        if (statNodes.getLength() > 0) {
                            Element stat = (Element)statNodes.item(0);
                            // System.out.println(stat.getElementsByTagName("status")
                            //       .item(0).getTextContent()); // child tag
                            Webresponse = stat.getElementsByTagName("status")
                                    .item(0).getTextContent();


                        }


                    }

                    catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    handler.post(createUI);
                }
            };

            thread.start();
        }


        final Runnable createUI = new Runnable() {


            public void run(){
    //          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    //                    Webresponse, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 


                    Intent i=new Intent(CheckLoginActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);

                startActivity(i);

                }
            }
        };

        }

      iam new to soap web service from above code i have done login web service from this if i entered username,password am getting the correct toast message i want to navigate next page how to do that thanks in advance.
```

if i entered correct password iam getting success in toast,i enterd worng password iam getting failed.

so what i need is if i enterd correct username and password it go to next page else incorrect usernam and password.so guys help me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you have to check the "Webresponse" like below.

```
if(Webresponse.equals("success"){
//open target activity
}else{
//show error message
}
```

Comment: i tried but it shows only toast SUCCESS not going to next activity

Comment: i put ur code in run method again it shows success only toast message  not moving to next activity

Comment: remove final before Runnable class and try

Comment: Runnable createUI = new Runnable() {
      

  public void run(){
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    Webresponse, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
         textview.setText(Webresponse);
         if(Webresponse.equals("SUCCESS")){
           Intent i=new Intent(CheckLoginActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);

                 startActivity(i);          }
         else{
          //show error message
          }

Comment: instead of    handler.post(createUI). use CheckLoginActivity.this.runOnUiThread(createUI);

Comment: catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

              //  handler.post(createUI);
             CheckLoginActivity.this.runOnUiThread(createUI);
            }

Comment: instead of thread use Async Task and start the Activity in onPostExecute method, may be that will work for you